# Is there a way to append output to a text field without taking focus?

Tags: c#, events, richtextbox

I'm trying to add text to a RichTextBox using the AppendText method, and would like to find a way to Not take focus of the text box in this motion - reason being that I have an event response to the text box getting focus, that causes a conflict in my overall scheme...

Again, the question here is effectively; How can I use the AppendText method without triggering focus on a rich text box.

As I'm typing this I've almost decided that I can remove my event response method before the append and add it in again after; but if anyone has a better suggestion I'm all ears.

Thanks. And if I can submit any code to spur suggestions I'm open to it; I just assume that most anyone using this site can visualize what I'm portraying.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a boolean variable to determine if it was you who fired the event (or the user)

```
bool firedByUser ;
```

When calling the **AppendText** method do something like this

```
firedByUser = false ;
rtb.AppendText("sample") ;
firedByUser = true ;
```

And in the method that you are handling the Focus on the RichTextBox

```
if(firedByUser)
{
    //keep doing what you are doing now
}
```

Comment: Valid suggestion and thank you - itll go in my bank of logical patterns to remember - however I still seem to feel that my own answer was probably optimal - as it requires the least amount of processing and memory usage thus far ( although truly negatable... )

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 maybe your question could be changed to read "is there a better way to append output to a text field without taking focus that the one I propose in my own question?" ;-)